# How to create an authentication token for Dynamics CRM

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have to migrate my data to Dynamics CRM using Mulesoft as an integration tool. I need to use integration APIs for this. The documentation of these APIs can be found here:
https://cloud-elements.github.io/docs/elements/dynamicscrm/ko/api-documentation.html?elementId=190#!/accounts/createAccount
But there is no API available here for the authentication. Also, I couldn't find any method to create token from any UI. I have created a free trial account on Azure and hence I am unable to create any permissions, previliges, users etc within my account.
Can someone share some information about how I can create an authentication token, in order to use the integration APIs to migrate data from my DB to Dynamics.

I tried following this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/generate-access-token-for-dynamics-365-single-tenant-server-to-server-authentica/ to somehow create a token etc but failed.

[I can not add any user or permission in Azure and get this error every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCWF7.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

To generate **access token** for Dynamics CRM, I used below parameters in Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://admin.services.crm.dynamics.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and got **`aud`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

In your case, the error usually occurs if you don't create **Azure Free trial** account properly.

When I signed in with my personal email account to Azure Portal directly without creating Free Trial, I got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

Go through below link to create **Free Trial** account.

**Reference:**
[How To Create Azure Free Account by **Onkar Sharma**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-azure-free-account/)

Comment: I tried following the article you mentioned: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-create-azure-free-account/ . I added my credit card which I hadn't done before. I have added permissions but can not add a user and got the same error mentioned above. Then, I tried to create a new account with different numbers but Azure redirected me to a page saying 'We’re unable to validate your phone number'. 
Can you tell me how can I get administrator role in a free trial account?

Comment: Could you confirm whether you can see **Free Trial** subscription in your Azure account or not after adding credit card?

Comment: where exactly can I check this?

Comment: I can't see **Free Trial** mentioned anywhere https://imgur.com/fBsYH1G

Comment: Go to Azure Active Directory -> Users -> Your user account -> Assigned Roles -> Add assignment -> Select Global Administrator role -> Assign like [this](https://i.imgur.com/AKKtDOn.png)

Comment: The content you shared, helped me a lot. I have successfully created an authentication token. Thanks a lot.